# How to make reference to jquery ui css values

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to take reference from the the jquery ui css with these codes. Placing them at different event handlers, yeild different values. Can someone help me on how I should go about getting these 4 ui css values. Thanks!

```
var ui_state_default_backgroundColor = $(".ui-state-default").css( "background-color" );

var ui_state_active_backgroundColor = $(".ui-state-active").css( "background-color" );

var ui_state_error_backgroundColor = $(".ui-state-error").css( "background-color" );

var ui_state_highlight_backgroundColor = $(".ui-state-highlight").css( "background-color" );


At $(document).ready(function() ..

.ui-state-default returns rgb(254,206,47) //correct values

.ui-state-active returns undefined

.ui-state-error returns undefined

.ui-state-highlight returns undefined

At $(window).load(function()..

.ui-state-default returns rgb(255,255,255) //wrong values

.ui-state-active returns rgb(255,255,255) //wrong values

.ui-state-error returns undefined

.ui-state-highlight returns undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing here would be that the jQuery code must only be tested and run under

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  /* codes here */
}
```

Then, the `undefined` term means that the element was not found or is undefined (method cannot be applied to it). You should first now check for the elements' classnames and then try the code.

Here is a fiddle that I have made up for you, http://jsfiddle.net/afzaal_ahmad_zeeshan/d8pBm/

You can go there and see, that none of the code that you're using is returning a `undefined`. They're giving out some value and the values are further being applied to other elements of the selected class names.

You should first have a look at the elements' class names.

Also, you should remember that if there is no element with a specified class, the result would be `undefined`. Which means if you're dynamically changing the classes of the elements and then applying styles, you'll always get the same result. And also, use

```
$(document).ready(function { /* code here */ })
```

instead of window load event.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Put your code within setTimeout, it may possible that your code get executed before the classes is added to the element.
Try like the following

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    SetTimeout(function(){
var ui_state_default_backgroundColor = $(".ui-state-default").css( "background-color" );
var ui_state_active_backgroundColor = $(".ui-state-active").css( "background-color" );
var ui_state_error_backgroundColor = $(".ui-state-error").css( "background-color" );
var ui_state_highlight_backgroundColor = $(".ui-state-highlight").css( "background-color"       );},200);});
```

Hope this will help you.